# How to add Typescript type definition generation in asp.net boilerplate

Tags: typescript, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I've seen issue [#415](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/415) solved for generating typescript files for ABP.

A couple of mount ago I started a project based on the  ABP template, Angular1 and EF but till now I have not found the way to add this feature to my VS project.

I have given a look to TypeScriptServiceGenerator.cs in the source codes, but I really don't know how to invoke it during my development process.

Does anybody has an example?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I created **t4** template(`TypeScriptTemplate.tt`) for generation **.d.ts**(`TypeScriptTemplate.d.ts`) annotation file for all rest API proxies(at case of AngularJS). Included it into `Web` project, so you can simple rebuild it and then ran corresponding **.tt** file, as a result **.d.ts** file will be created with bunch of interfaces and you can use them as intellisence and for validation purposes on client side **during development**. You can view more info with example at [rejected pull request](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/pull/76). Code, that actually do all work, is located at `TypeScriptGenerator.cs`:

Excerpt from autogenerated output **.d.ts** file:

```
interface UserAppService {
    prohibitPermission(input: ProhibitPermissionInput, ajaxParams?: JQueryAjaxSettings): AbpResultVoid;
    removeFromRole(userId: number, roleName: string, ajaxParams?: JQueryAjaxSettings): AbpResultVoid;
    getUsers(ajaxParams?: JQueryAjaxSettings): AbpResult<ListResultDto<UserListDto>>;
    createUser(input: CreateUserInput, ajaxParams?: JQueryAjaxSettings): AbpResultVoid;
 }
```

[image]